# regex to find integers in string not matching

Tags: java, regex

I have two tables' contents stored in Stringbuffers. One has data in it; the other is only a header. I converted the Stringbuffers into Strings and removed whitespace.

table1:

> ACCOUNT_NUMBER;BRANCH_CODE;RECALC_ACTION_CODE;RECALC_DATE;PROCESS_NO;PRINCIPAL_CHG_AMXX23QRUP120970003;023;E;05.09.2013;1;-522.53

table2:

> ACCOUNT_NUMBER;BRANCH_CODE;MSG_TYPE

I only want to proceed with a table if it has data in it, like table1.
To check for data (i.e integers) I used regex: `table1.matches("\\d")`, but this returns false. I also tried `table1.matches("(?s)\\d"))`, for new line character but even this returns false.

How can I check for integer data in the strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [documentation on `matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29). The "match" requires the entire string to match, and so your `table1.matches("\\d")` fails -- "table1" is not 'one digit only'.

Use `table1.matches(".*\\d.*")` instead. Note the double backslash! You might not be aware they need escaping in a String constant.

Comment: hi,thankyou for your quick reply. yes i was using double backslash.

Comment: just modified your suggestion to table1.matches("(?s).*\\d.*")) and now it works. Thanks alot!!

Comment: Upvoting clear answer that manages to both reference the documentation and solve the problem within a few lines. :)